# Setting javascript variable to use in div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables, html

So I have this example here where I have javascript variable "id" which I want to put into a divs id.

```
<div id="(var id here)" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:5px solid black; ">

</div>

<script>
var id;

var color = blue

$('#(var id here)').css({"background-color" : color});
</script>
```

This is just an example and it's important that the div id is the variable id, not just a name. Hope someone can help me. Ask me if you don't understand! Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to *set* the div's `id` to the variable `id`? Also, use `var color = "blue";` otherwise you'll get an undefined variable error.

Comment: What do you want now ?

Comment: You are asking how to use a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#' + id).css({"background-color" : color});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 1;

$('div').attr('id', id).css('background-color', 'blue');
```

The selector isn't really good but I don't know how you create your `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it the wrong way.

What you need to do is create different css class with different attribute.

```
.blue{ background-color : blue; }
.green{ background-color : green; }
```

And then, with your js code, you load the selected class to the element.

Note: this isn't a good answer to your question but a different way to do it.

Hope this help